# Accessibility - RatingBar gets auto-focused

Tags: android, accessibility

> Use Case: Accessibility  - Auto-focus on RatingBar: Start speaking the content description as soon as the screen renders or the value of the view is updated.  I don't want it to auto-focus and start speaking. It should speak when a user does focus.

I have RatingBar in my Layout which gets an auto-focus as soon as that layout is rendered on the screen.

```
 <FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >
 ...
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
      ...
     android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
     android:contentDescription="@{@string/no_of_reviews_displayed_ada(rating)}"
     android:rating="@{rating}"
     />
 ...
 </FrameLayout>
```

The rating is being set via `Observable` whenever I have a response from API.

```
vm.getRatingsData().observe(this, rating -> {
  binding.setRating(rating);
});
```

As soon as the layout renders & rating is set, accessibility starts to speak out the rating without being manually focused.

What I tried:

- Requesting focus to other elements by default. But somehow on `setRating`; `AppCompatRatingBar` gets the focus. To me, it seems they waay is been inherited from ProgressBar which is input based view.
- Setting `importantForAccessibility` as `no` by default and changing after getting the value on observable. Though this seems tricky as it requires some duration gap to make it work

> Is there any Accessibility Listener that I can hook into this RatingBar and listen when it gets actual focus and send the Accessibility Event?

Comment: Are you sure there is no problem with GTalk settings. I meant we have `RatingBar` in the layout and accessibility service is working fine. It announce  rating only when user touched it. Or when GTalk configured to read whole page.

Answer (score 0):

By checking [the source code of the RatingBar](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/RatingBar.java) I discovered this:

```
@Override
public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(info);

    if (canUserSetProgress()) {
        info.addAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessibilityAction.ACTION_SET_PROGRESS);
    }
}

@Override
boolean canUserSetProgress() {
    return super.canUserSetProgress() && !isIndicator();
}
```

So your code could be solved by changing your code to:

```
vm.getRatingsData().observe(this, rating -> {
  rating_bar.setIsIndicator(true)
  binding.setRating(rating);
  rating_bar.setIsIndicator(false)
});
```

Otherwise, if the user doesn't have to change the rating value you could set the isIndicator value straight from the xml.